# Calculated Column - # of Unique Values Within Column

Tags: 2010, calculated-column

I have a time off calendar. What I would like for a column to do is count and update the number of unique values for that day.

Here is an example:

Day Off     |||||     # of Values

12/1/13      |||||     1

12/2/13      |||||         3

12/2/13      ||||| 3

12/2/13   |||||     3

12/4/13    |||||      2

12/4/13  |||||     2

So if you can see, I would like for the column to count the value provided in the “Day Off” column and count that value amongst the rest of the column.

Hope that makes sense and can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Calculated columns only work with data in the same item.  You cannot do SUMs or other calculations that require data from other items in the list.

You could, however, accomplish what you are looking for by using the Grouping options in your view of the list.  You can group by the date and then you will get a count of the items in that group.

Comment: Thanks John. I had a fear that it wouldn't work that way. If I did a grouping, would that number be available in a calculation? The reason I ask is because I want to have an Nintex Workflow start based on if there are multiple entries on the same day with a Leave Type of "Vacation." Thus I need to count the number of vacation entries for a given day, then run the workflow if that number is greater than (1).

Comment: No, it wouldn't be available in a calculation.  You might ask Nintex if there is a better way to kick off the workflow for your scenario...

Comment: You'd just need to have an action in the workflow to query list and add in the specific dynamic filters you want, store that in a collection and use a collection operation to get a count and then do what ever logic you need after that.